# If you had a Mac that was not going to ever connect to the internet, what would you do to optimize it?

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

I have a Mac Pro at work in a lab environment that is connected to a bunch of lab equipment that will never be connected to the internet. I've noticed that if I open up the console application to look at the streaming logs, there a lot of errors (which look mostly like the Mac is trying to call out to the internet and failing). While this doesn't really matter, I was wondering what settings you would apply to optimize a Mac like this (e.g. disabling OCSP checks, etc.)

Disclaimer, I a more of a Windows/Linux user so assume very little Mac knowledge!

Cheers!

Edit: The Mac is on a network and wifi has been disabled.

Comment: Is this Mac connected to a network at all for intranet/LAN/etc.? And if it's not, is the WiFi option disabled?

Comment: The Mac is connected to a network with the lab equipment on it. Wifi is disabled.

Comment: Which application(s) is trying to access the internet?

Comment: assistand, trustd, a bunch of builtin Mac things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is worth your while to prevent the Mac from attempting access to the internet as that is inherent to every app design.

But if you need to force the Mac to remain disconnected from the internet (wireless or wired) I would hard code a good IP for the LAN or WLAN not in the DHCP scope but in the same subnet (you may need to adjust your routers DHCP).  **Then set a WRONG gateway address** to prevent the computer from getting out.

Let me know if this helps or you need further explanation.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: this will NOT get rid of the logging error the OP is complaining about and he stated that the Mac is connected to a Lab Network which does not have an Internet connection. Setting a wrong gateway might even introduce more errors if his Lab has multiple subnets.

Comment: The Mac will not connect to the internet. It is not on a network that connects to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a firewall to block all internet access, with the exception of the
IP segment of the local network.
The applications that do these accesses to the internet will hopefully
then terminate themselves or at least cease trying.

You could use the
[application firewall](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201642)
built-into MacOS.
I have also heard of the
[Lulu](https://objective-see.com/products/lulu.html) open-source firewall and of
[Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html)
(commercial).